# DataFrame tolist for multiple column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

How to do add a new column that contains a list of the current columns `'bar4': [[5,1,11],[6,2,22],[5,3,33]]` in the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

foo1 = (['L1','L1','L2'])
foo2 = ([5,5,6])
foo3 = ([1,1,2])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [foo1,foo2,foo3], names=['ifoo1','ifoo2','ifoo3']
    )
init = pd.DataFrame({
    'bar1': [5,6,5],
    'bar2': [1,2,3],
    'bar3': [11,22,33]
    }, index=index)
```

I initially thought it would be a similar operation to something `init['barX'] = init.bar1 + init.bar2`, but `int['bar4'] = init.bar1, init.bar2, init.bar3` is definately not the solution.

Desired result:

```
 #                 bar1  bar2 bar3 bar4
 # foo1 foo2 foo3
 # L1   5    1      5    1    11   [5,1,11]
 # L1   5    1      6    2    22   [6,2,22]
 # L2   6    2      5    3    33   [5,3,33]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need convert values to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) with [`numpy.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
init['bar4'] = init.values.tolist()
print (init)
                   bar1  bar2  bar3        bar4
ifoo1 ifoo2 ifoo3                              
L1    5     1         5     1    11  [5, 1, 11]
            1         6     2    22  [6, 2, 22]
L2    6     2         5     3    33  [5, 3, 33]
```

And if need specify columns:

```
cols = ['bar1','bar2','bar3']
init['bar4'] = init[cols].values.tolist()
print (init)
                   bar1  bar2  bar3        bar4
ifoo1 ifoo2 ifoo3                              
L1    5     1         5     1    11  [5, 1, 11]
            1         6     2    22  [6, 2, 22]
L2    6     2         5     3    33  [5, 3, 33]
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest may just be to use [`tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) on the underlying NumPy ndarray.

```
init['bar4'] = init.values.tolist()
```

Or if you need to specify a subset of columns of data,

```
init['bar4'] = init.loc[:, 'bar1':'bar3'].values.tolist()
```